# Jest/testing-library cannot find content in nested components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the following `Form` component with two nested components (`Input` and `Greeting`):

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Form() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Form</p>
      <Greeting />
      <Input label="first name" id="firstname" />
      <Input label="last name" id="lastname" />
    </div>
  );
}

function Input({ label, id }: { label:string, id:string }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <input id={id} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Greeting() {
  return <div>Hello</div>;
}
```

And I have this Jest and `@testing-library/react` test:

```
test('All input fields are displayed', allFieldsAreDisplayed);
test('Greeting displayed', greetingDisplayed);

function allFieldsAreDisplayed() {
  render(<Form />);
  const firstNameInput = screen.getByText('first name');
  expect(firstNameInput).toBeInTheDocument();
}

function greetingDisplayed() {
  render(<Form />);
  const greeting = screen.getByText('Hello');
  expect(greeting).toBeInTheDocument();
}
```

However, when I run the test to see if both are displayed, I get the below error messages:

```
 TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: first name. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.   

    Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
    <body />

      12 | function allFieldsAreDisplayed() {
      13 |   render(<Form />);
    > 14 |   const firstNameInput = screen.getByText('first name');
         |                                 ^
      15 |   expect(firstNameInput).toBeInTheDocument();
      16 | }
      17 |
```

And:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Hello. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.        

Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
<body />

  18 | function greetingDisplayed() {
  19 |   render(<Form />);
> 20 |   const greeting = screen.getByText('Hello');
     |                           ^
  21 |   expect(greeting).toBeInTheDocument();
  22 | }
  23 |
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue.